# The Search for Dracula - a puzzle

Tags: knowledge, cipher

Some friends and I are playing a roleplaying game about Dracula in the modern age. Last night, we received the following puzzle from the game-master.

**(7 1 1 1 1) (17 8 8 8 8) (4313 2755)**

With the following information that might help:

- It is 'real' information. So no fictional stuff, and it is applicable in the real world.
- We suspect the last part to be coordinates to a village in Bulgaria (the person we received the transmission from is a secret agent in the Balkans).
- The message was received by morse-code. (but no idea if this is relevant).

Is this a familiar pattern? Maybe you guys and gals can solve this one!

Comment: taking the last pair as coordinates, we have (43.13, 27.55: https://www.google.com/maps/place/43%C2%B007'48.0%22N+27%C2%B033'00.0%22E/@43.1300039,27.547806,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d43.13!4d27.55) or (43 degrees 13 minutes, etc. https://www.google.com/maps/place/43%C2%B013'01.2%22N+27%C2%B055'01.2%22E/@43.217019,27.9186175,17.4z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d43.217!4d27.917

Comment: That's the part we had kinda figured out. But the first part is still a mystery. Thanks for the help though!